# Interpolation of a linear operator acting on a sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces, harmonic-analysis

Let $\mathbf{f} = \{f_{n}\}$ be a sequence of Schwarz functions and suppose $T$ is a linear operator which sends a given sequence of Schwarz functions to a given function in $L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for all $p$. Suppose for some $1 \leq q_{1}< q_{2} \leq \infty$, we had $\|T\mathbf{f}\|_{L^{q_i}} \leq C_{i}(\sum_{n}\|f_{n}\|_{L^{q_i}}^{q_i})^{1/q_i}$. Is it true that for $q_{1} \leq q \leq q_{2}$, $$\|T\mathbf{f}\|_{L^{q}} \lesssim (\sum_{n}\|f_{n}\|_{L^{q}}^{q})^{1/q}?$$

I imagine this is an application of some sort of interpolation since I can write the right hand side as $\|T\mathbf{f}\|_{L^{q}} \leq C_{i}\|\mathbf{f}\|_{L^{q}_{x}\ell_{n}^{q}}$ where the $L^{q}_{x}\ell_{n}^{q}$ norm is defined by we first take the $L^{q}_{x}$ norm of each term then take the $\ell_{n}^{q}$ norm.

Comment: When you write $\|T\mathbf{f}\|_{L^{q_{i}}}\leq C_{i}(\sum_{n}\|f_{n}\|_{L^{q_{i}}}^{q_{i}})^{1/q_{i}}$, this is suppose to be for $i=1,2$?

Comment: @MattRosenzweig: Yes, that relation is supposed to be true for $i = 1, 2$.

Comment: Ok, I believe I have a proof of the result you want using the real interpolation method. I believe one can probably prove your theorem using the complex method, as well, but it's not clear to me right now how to do that. I'll think about it some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the result is true--unless I'm making an error below--and even holds under the weaker hypothesis
$$\|T\mathbf{f}\|_{L^{q_{i},\infty}}\leq C_{i}\|\mathbf{f}\|_{L_{x}^{q_{i}}\ell_{n}^{q_{i}}},\quad\forall i=1,2$$

To prove this, we mimic the proof of the Marcinkiewicz interpolation theorem. For $\delta>0$ be a parameter to be determined later. For $\lambda>0$, we write $\mathbf{f}=\mathbf{f}_{1}^{\lambda}+\mathbf{f}_{2}^{\lambda}$, where
$$\mathbf{f}_{1}^{\lambda}:=\{f_{n}1_{|f_{n}|>\delta\lambda}\}_{n}=\{f_{1,n}^{\lambda}\}_{n}\enspace \mathbf{f}_{2}^{\lambda}:=\{f_{n}1_{|f_{n}|\leq\delta\lambda}\}_{n}=\{f_{2,n}^{\lambda}\}_{n}$$

By the triangle inequality together with Chebyshev and the hypotheses, we have the estimate
\begin{align*}
|\{|T\mathbf{f}|>\lambda\}|&\leq|\{|T\mathbf{f}_{1}^{\lambda}|>\lambda/2\}|+|\{|T\mathbf{f}_{2}^{\lambda}|>\lambda/2\}|\\
&\leq \dfrac{2^{q_{1}}\|T\mathbf{f}_{1}^{\lambda}\|_{L^{q_{1}}}^{q_{1}}}{\lambda^{q_{1}}}+\dfrac{2^{q_{2}}\|T\mathbf{f}\|_{L^{q_{2}}}^{q_{2}}}{\lambda^{q_{2}}}\\
&\leq\dfrac{2^{q_{1}}(C_{1}\|\mathbf{f}_{1}^{\lambda}\|_{L_{x}^{q_{1}}\ell_{n}^{q_{1}}})^{q_{1}}}{\lambda^{q_{1}}}+\dfrac{2^{q_{2}}(C_{2}\|\mathbf{f}_{2}^{\lambda}\|_{L_{x}^{q_{2}}\ell_{n}^{q_{2}}})^{q_{2}}}{\lambda^{q_{2}}}
\end{align*}

Using the layer cake formula, we have the estimate
\begin{align*}
\|T\mathbf{f}\|_{L^{q}}^{q}&=q\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda^{q-1}|\{|T\mathbf{f}|>\lambda\}|d\lambda\\
&\leq (2C_{1})^{q_{1}}q\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda^{q-q_{1}-1}\sum_{n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}|f_{1,n}^{\lambda}|^{q_{1}}dxd\lambda\\
&+(2C_{2})^{q_{2}}q\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda^{q-q_{2}-1}\sum_{n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}|f_{2,n}^{\lambda}|^{q_{2}}dxd\lambda\\
&=(2C_{1})^{q_{1}}q\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda^{q-q_{1}-1}\sum_{n}\int_{\{|f_{n}|>\delta\lambda\}}|f_{n}|^{q_{1}}dxd\lambda\\
&+(2C_{2})^{q_{2}}q\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda^{q-q_{2}-1}\sum_{n}\int_{\{|f_{n}|\leq\delta\lambda\}}|f_{n}|^{q_{2}}dxd\lambda
\end{align*}
By monotone convergence, we can pull the sum outside the outer integrals. By Fubini-Tonelli,
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda^{q-q_{1}-1}\int_{\{|f_{n}|>\delta\lambda\}}|f_{n}(x)|^{q_{1}}dxd\lambda&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}|f_{n}(x)|^{q_{1}}\int_{0}^{\delta^{-1}|f_{n}(x)|}\lambda^{q-q_{1}-1}d\lambda dx\\
&=\dfrac{\delta^{-q+q_{1}}}{q-q_{1}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}|f_{n}|^{q}dx\\
\end{align*}
Similarly,
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda^{q-q_{2}-1}\int_{\{|f_{n}|\leq\delta\lambda\}}|f_{n}(x)|^{q_{2}}dx d\lambda&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}|f_{n}(x)|^{q_{2}}\int_{\delta^{-1}|f_{n}(x)|}^{\infty}\lambda^{q-q_{2}-1}d\lambda dx\\
&=\dfrac{\delta^{-q+q_{2}}}{(q_{2}-q)}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}|f_{n}|^{q}dx
\end{align*}
Combining these two results, we obtain that
\begin{align*}
\|T\mathbf{f}\|_{L^{q}}^{q}&\leq \sum_{n}\left[\dfrac{(2C_{1})^{q_{1}}q}{q-q_{1}}\delta^{-q+q_{1}}+\dfrac{(2C_{2})^{q_{2}}q}{q_{2}-q}\delta^{-q+q_{2}}\right]\|f_{n}\|_{L^{q}}^{q}\\
&=\left[\dfrac{(2C_{1})^{q_{1}}q}{q-q_{1}}\delta^{-q+q_{1}}+\dfrac{(2C_{2})^{q_{2}}q}{q_{2}-q}\delta^{-q+q_{2}}\right]\|\mathbf{f}\|_{L_{x}^{q}\ell_{n}^{q}}^{q}
\end{align*}
Choosing $\delta$ so that both terms inside the brackets are equal and then taking $q^{th}$ roots completes the proof.

Comment: I was playing around with the exponents. Let's suppose $C_{1} = C_{2} = 1$ and $q_{1} = 1$, $q_{2} = 2$. Then I think the optimal delta is $\delta = \frac{1}{2}\frac{2 - q}{q - 1}$ and this gives that $\|T\mathbf{f}\|_{L^q} \leq \frac{2}{(2 - q)^{1/q}}\left(\frac{2 - q}{q - 1}\right)^{2/q - 1}\|\mathbf{f}\|_{L^{q}_{x}\ell^{q}_{n}}$ and the constant actually blows up at $q = 1, 2$. I wonder if the argument can be made tighter somewhere so this doesn't happen.

Comment: @user187437: That the constants blow up at $q_{i}$ should be expected. The real method uses weak type bound hypotheses (which we passed to by Chebyshev), so you shouldn't expect a priori to get strong type. Do you take issue with proof given, though?

Comment: The proof seems fine though, thanks!